# React, `onClick` using old value of state even thought it's not capturing it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a mildly complex setup for tabs and tab slots, to make them modular and generic. I've decided to create a context and a provider for this and expose ways to manipulate tabs and slots (slots are what is being displayed in the current tab).

But what I found very weird is that my callback that you can call to change the slot, *only on the first render* is using the old state. Let me show

```js
export const TabProvider: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<{}>> = ({ children }) => {
    const [tabComponents, setTabComponents] = useState<TabComponent[]>([]);
    const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState("");
    const [currentSlot, setCurrentSlot] = useState<TabSlot>({ label: "", component: null, id: "" })

    useEffect(() => {

        console.log("Use Effect", currentTab, tabComponents, currentSlot)
    }, [currentSlot, tabComponents, currentTab])

    const setCurrentSlotHelper = (slotId: string) => {
        console.log("On Click", slotId, tabComponents, currentSlot, currentTab)
        tabComponents.forEach(component => {
            component.slots.forEach(slot => {
                if (slot.id == slotId) {
                    setCurrentSlot(slot)
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

If we look at the console

[image: screenshot of console to showcase the empty output]

We can see that the on click one does not have the correct state.

We can see the correct state in the devtools as well

```
[
  {
    "name": "State",
    "value": [
      "{id: \"dashboard\", label: \"Dashboard\", onCurrent: ƒ …}",
      "{id: \"content\", label: \"Content\", onCurrent: ƒ onCu…}",
      "{id: \"studio\", label: \"Studio\", onCurrent: ƒ onCurr…}"
    ],
    "subHooks": [],

]
```

I know that this can potentially occur if we use a closure and capture the state, but that is not what I am doing here, and it works if I manage navigate to another tab and back. So there is something really funky happening and I need a React wizard to help me decipher this.

The tab provider

```js
const TabContext = createContext<TabContextProps>(defaultState);

export const useTab = () => useContext(TabContext);

export const TabProvider: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<{}>> = ({ children }) => {
    const [tabComponents, setTabComponents] = useState<TabComponent[]>([]);
    const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState("");
    const [currentSlot, setCurrentSlot] = useState<TabSlot>({ label: "", component: null, id: "" })

    useEffect(() => {

        console.log("Use Effect", currentTab, tabComponents, currentSlot)
    }, [currentSlot, tabComponents, currentTab])

    const setCurrentSlotHelper = (slotId: string) => {
        console.log("On Click", slotId, tabComponents, currentSlot, currentTab)
        tabComponents.forEach(component => {
            component.slots.forEach(slot => {
                if (slot.id == slotId) {
                    setCurrentSlot(slot)
                }
            })
        })
    }

    const setTabComponentsHelper = (components: TabComponent[]) => ...

    const setCurrentTabHelper = (tabId: string) =>...

    return (
        <TabContext.Provider
            value={{
                tabComponents, setTabComponents: setTabComponentsHelper, currentTab, setCurrentTab: setCurrentTabHelper, currentSlot, setCurrentSlot: setCurrentSlotHelper
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </TabContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

The way its used

```js
export const Template = () => {
    const { sidebarComponents, setSidebarComponents } = useSidebar()
    const { setTabComponents, currentSlot, setCurrentSlot } = useTab();

    useEffect(() => {
        let newTabs: TabComponent[] = [];
        // When the tab changes, update the sidebar components, and set default slot
        const onTabChange = (tab: TabComponent) => {
            const newSlotId = tab.slots[0].id
            const sidebarComponents: SidebarComponent[] = []
            tab.slots.forEach(slot => {
                const slotId = slot.label.toLowerCase()
                sidebarComponents.push({
                    id: slotId,
                    label: slot.label,
                    isCurrent: newSlotId == slotId,
                    onClick: () => setCurrentSlot(slotId)
                })
            })

            setCurrentSlot(newSlotId) // <- here we're calling it
            setSidebarComponents(sidebarComponents)
        }

        const tabs = ecommerceTabs;

        for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            const tab = tabs[i]
            const tabComponent: TabComponent = {
                id: tab.label.toLowerCase(),
                label: tab.label,
                slots: tab.slots.map(slot => {
                    return {
                        ...slot, id: slot.label.toLowerCase()
                    }
                }),
                onCurrent: () => {
                    onTabChange(tabComponent)
                }
            }
            newTabs.push(tabComponent)
        }

        onTabChange(newTabs[0])

        setTabComponents(newTabs)
    }, [])

    // When the current slot changes, update the sidebar components
    useEffect(() => {
        if (sidebarComponents.length == 0) return;
        setSidebarComponents(
            sidebarComponents.map(component => {
                component.isCurrent = component.label.toLowerCase() == currentSlot.id
                return component
            })
        );
    }, [currentSlot])

    return (<></>)
};
```

Comment: `onTabChange` which calls `setCurrentSlot` is only created once on mount due to the empty dependency array `[]`. So `onTabChange` refers to the original `setCurrentSlot` function from the initial mounts, which only knows about the initial state. So you do in fact have a closure issue here.

Comment: @NickParsons  But the current state used in the `setCurrentSlotHelper` is being taken from the outer function, its not being captured by the closure. So every time that function is invoked it should reach out to the `tabComponents` variable and get the latest value? I don't see how its capturing it, or is this some React specify gotcha?

Comment: Yes, the current state in `setCurrentSlotHelper` does come from the outer scope, but remember `TabProvider` will be rerendered multiple times, recreating the `TabProvider` scope & creating new state variables in that scope, as well as recreating `setCurrentSlotHelper` for each new render that now knows about the new state values. However, the new `setCurrentSlotHelper` that get created on future renders (that know about the new state values), are never used, since your `useEffect` only runs on initial mount, & so `setCurrentSlot` is the initial function that knows about the initial state only.

Comment: @NickParsons honestly never would've thought that this is what is happening internally with the variables. Can you write up the solution with the above mentioned explanation and I'll accept it. I am pressuming the useEffect has to have the dependencies that will update the closures. I moved away from this approach in favor of a `zustand` store, and it made things much less cognitively taxing. But this could be useful for future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has to do with your `useEffect()` in `Template` only running once on mount. As it defines the `onClick` on-mount, it references the original  `setCurrentSlot` from the original render rather than the new/latest `setCurrentSlot` function created by subsequent renders (which know about the latest state).

---

Each time your state within `TabProvider` changes your component rerenders. This means that `TabProvider` is called once on the initial render, and then potentially many more times for each rerender when your state changes. Every render that occurs calls the `TabProvider` function again, recreating the `TabProvider` function scope and the variables that live within that, including the states `tabComponents`, `currentTab`, `currentSlot` which are set to the new/latest state values. Along with the state variables being recreated, so is the `setCurrentSlotHelper` function, which now knows about the new state variables in its surrounding scope that it was declared in.

You can think of each rerender of `TabProvider` as being "snapshots", each snapshot having its own state variables and functions defined with `TabProvider`.

Your problem is that within `Template` you're using a `useEffect()` with an empty dependency array `[]`. That means that your `useEffect()` will run on-mount only. At the time that your `useEffect()` runs, your state values from `TabProvider` are in their initial states still, and the function `setCurrentSlot` is the `setCurrentSlotHelper` function from the initial render (ie: first snapshot) of the `Template` function. That means that `setCurrentSlot` only knows about the initial state variables from the initial render/snapshot. Technically speaking, your `useEffect` callback function here has formed a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over the initial `setCurrentSlot` function, and your `setCurrentSlot` function has formed a closure over the initial state variable values.

As your state then changes in `TabProvider`, you create new "snapshots" and new `setCurrentSlotHelper` for each rerender, however, since your `useEffect()` function will not run again (since it only runs on initial mount due), the reference to the new `setCurrentSlotHelper` won't reestablish, and instead, your `useEffect()` callback will continue to look at the initial `setCurrentSlotHelper` from the first render/snapshot.

---

There are usually a few different ways to fix this, but its a bit hard to tell what's best to do in your scenario as it's not too clear how `tabs` is being used. Normally you'd want to delegate the `onClick` and event-handler logic to the JSX rather than setting it up in your `useEffect()`. You may also find that adding `setCurrentSlot` (and `setSidebarComponents`) as dependencies to your `useEffect()` is another way around this (if you do that, then you would want to look at [memoizing these functions with `useCallback()`](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#moving-functions-inside-effects)).

Answer (score 0):

Since updating a state is an async task it takes some time to update the state and since youre setting state inside a loop it creates a lag. You can do something like this:

```
const setCurrentSlotHelper = (slotId: string) => {
    let tempSlot = {...currentSlot};
    console.log("On Click", slotId, tabComponents, currentSlot, currentTab)
    tabComponents.forEach(component => {
        component.slots.forEach(slot => {
            if (slot.id == slotId) {
                tempSlot = slot;
            }
        })
    })
    setCurrentSlot(tempSlot)
}
```

In this I am doing all the data manipulations in a local variable which is not async and doing the setting of state in the end once which saves us from slower renders and You will get proper console logs in your useEffect.